# Is there a function to scrape the notes sections of Powerpoint Slides?

Tags: r, ms-office, powerpoint, officer

I am attempting to read through ~ 100 powerpoint slides and read the notes sections of each slide. I will do some text wrangling and write to csv after the fact, but need to get the notes in a workable format first.

I am working with the `officer` package, `read_pptx` function right now, but am open to whatever packages needed. It doesn't seem to pull in notes, but I may just be looking at this wrong.

To show a bit of what I've tried -->

```
library(officer)

ppt_var <- read_pptx('test_presentation.pptx')
view(ppt_var)
```

Ideally, I could get the text of each notes slide added to individual variables to write to a csv. I am confident that I can handle the manipulation once I get the notes read in, but cannot seem to get that part down.

Thank you for any pointers or support!

Comment: You can always read them from the `xml` file. I don't know of a package that will do it for you.

Comment: All office files are zipped XML. Unzip it, read the xml, you should be able to find the notes.

Comment: Other option would be writing a VB Script and run that from R. Look here for the vbs tip. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.notespage

Comment: or `C#`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164819/how-to-programmatically-read-and-change-slide-notes-in-powerpoint

Comment: This question is specifically about the officer package so I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

How do do that is shown in the code here:  https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/117 .

The following is based on that code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(officer)
library(xml2)

p <- read_pptx("mypresentation.pptx")
notes_dir <- file.path(p$package_dir, "ppt", "notesSlides")
files <- list.files(pattern = ".xml$", path = notes_dir, full.names = TRUE)

Notes <- lapply(files,
 . %>% 
   read_xml %>%
   xml_find_all("//a:t") %>%
   xml_text
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the Document.OpenXML dependencies in C#, a more native way would be:

```
    public static SlidePart GetSlidePart(PresentationDocument pptxDoc, int index)
    {
        // Get the relationship ID of the first slide.
        PresentationPart presentationPart = pptxDoc.PresentationPart;
        OpenXmlElementList slideIds = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;
        string relId = (slideIds[index] as SlideId).RelationshipId;

        // Get the slide part from the relationship ID.
        return (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(relId);
    }

    public static string GetNoteText(PresentationDocument pptxDoc, int index)
    {
        //Get the Slide Part
        SlidePart slidePart = GetSlidePart(pptxDoc, index);
        //Extract the Note text
        return slidePart.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: That's a big assumption, as the question is tagged r and not C#.